# NullReferenceException in 'if' statement C#

Tags: c#, string, contains, indexof

This is a simple program of string array and string manipulation.

I have a string array called `list` that has strings that represent a single line of a file that I read earlier (each line contains DNA chemical sequence like `AGCTTTTCATTCT`).

This `getStrands()` method is supposed to take out each individual line (which is a single element in `list`) that contains a desired substring called `sequence` (like "CATTCT") and put all of these lines with the sequence into another string array called `result` and return it.

```css
    public static string[] getStrands(string[] list, string sequence)
        {
            List<string> temp = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
            {
                string x = list[i];
                if (x.IndexOf(sequence) != -1)
                    temp.Add(x);
            }

            //converts temp List into a string[] to return
            string[] result = new string[temp.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++)
                result[i] = temp.ElementAt(i);

            return result;
        }
```

The error:
    System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The error occurs at this line: `if (x.IndexOf(sequence) != -1)`

I checked to see if `x` or `sequence` was `null`, but they're not. How come when I try to see if `x` contains `sequence`, it gives me this error (I also tried the Contains() method and it gave me the same error)?

Comment: Please debug and you'll certainly find the issue yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

On the code you don't check if `list` is `null` (which would throw on the line `for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)` nor you check for null on each element, that would throw on the line that you said on your question.

Comment: Thank you so much! I added an if statement: `if (x == null)
                    continue;` to check for null. It worked.

Comment: If the answer helped please select this to be the most helpful answer!

Comment: One mechanism that I use with functions that take parameter by reference (any `object` accounts for it) is to actually throw `ArgumentNullException`, `ArgumentException`... depending on the case IF the input is NOT expected to not be null. One easy way to check it is to ask yourself "is it valid for the input to be null? how the function should behave if the input is null?", if the answer is "input shouldn't be null" then throw, otherwise code accordingly. Welcome to Stack Overflow, and if the answer helped you please hit the check at the left =)

Comment: @GuillermoMestre Reference types *aren't* passed by reference by default in C#. References are passed by value in C# unless the `ref` or `out` modifiers are used.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot you are right, I wanted to say "any parameter that is a reference type" but said it the other way around. Definitely yesterday was not my day :P

Answer (score 0):

As Guillermo said, you should be checking `null` before accessing those items:

```
public static string[] getStrands(string[] list, string sequence)
{
    if (list == null) {
        return null;
    }
    List<string> temp = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] != null) {
            string x = list[i];
            if (x.IndexOf(sequence) != -1)
                temp.Add(x);
        }
    }

    //converts temp List into a string[] to return
    string[] result = new string[temp.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++)
        result[i] = temp.ElementAt(i);

    return result;
}
```